# How can i check for multiple values in the same variable SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, oracle

SO basically, i want to return "cid" (customer id's) of users who has ordered a certain product "p07 & p01".

My currently query don't work, it only works when i check for one value instead of two. But i need it to check for two.  The return value i get is basically an empty space. My guess is, it doesn't know which "pid" to use so it returns nothing.

```
SELECT cid FROM orders 
WHERE pid = 'p07' AND pid = 'p01'
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data and expected result? Also please tag your question with appropriate RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation for this purpose.  No single row can have both values, so you need to look at groups of them:

```
SELECT cid
FROM orders 
WHERE pid IN ('p07', 'p01')
GROUP BY cid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pid) = 2;
```

Comment: I assume you mean `WHERE pid = 'p07' OR pid = 'p01'` not `AND` (or `WHERE pid IN ('p01', 'p07')`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you explain what the "group by" and "having" count do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ***Oracle database*** than you can use the ***INTERSECT*** keyword to get the answer. Following is the syntax for the same:

(SELECT cid FROM orders where pid = 'p07')
 intersect
(SELECT cid FROM orders where pid = 'p01').

but if you are using MySQL, than this ***INTERSECT*** keyword will not work.

Following is the solution for the ***MySql database***:

SELECT t1.cid from (
  (SELECT DISTINCT cid FROM orders where pid = 'p07')
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT DISTINCT cid FROM orders where pid = 'p01')
) AS t1 GROUP BY cid HAVING count(*) >= 2;

If you want to use the above query in the ***Oracle database*** than there is a bit change in the syntax. Following is the syntax for the same:

SELECT t1.cid from (
  (SELECT DISTINCT cid FROM orders where pid = 'p07')
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT DISTINCT cid FROM orders where pid = 'p01')
) t1 GROUP BY cid HAVING count(*) > = 2